# Creating a single distributable jar file for Android projects which includes other jar files

Tags: android, jar, onejar

My objective is to create a single distributable jar file for Android projects which includes a few other jar files. As I understand a "standard" jar file is not allowed to have other jar files inside, so guess I need to learn a trick here.

- I have been trying to set up [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) for this, but I keep hitting
  issues. Are there any dev guides for using One-jar with Android projects (using Eclipse)?
- Are there any other good alternatives out there I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

[jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) is pretty good at this. When you use it [together](http://sonatype.github.com/jarjar-maven-plugin/) with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) its super easy to make a large collection of dependencies a single jar.

Although, there's nothing stopping you including multiple jars as dependencies in an Android project.